# Confirm number of occurrences of a objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a huge difficulty in creating a program to check the number of occurrences of objects in array based on rules set by me. If a particular object exists more then one, I count the number of occurrences.

Example input:

```
[
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}',
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}',
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}'
]
```

Example output:

```
[
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":3}}}'
]
```

**WARNING: THIS IS A EXAMPLE.**

So, how i'm doing:

```js
let SUPER = [
  {"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}},
  {"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}},
  {"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}},
  {"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}
],
FINAL = [];

for (let _super of SUPER) {
  _super = JSON.stringify(_super);
  let ii = 0, ll = SUPER.length, number = 0;

  for (ii; ii < ll; ii++) {
    let current = JSON.stringify(SUPER[ii]);
    if (_super === current) {
      SUPER.splice(ii, 1);
      number++;
    }
  }

  if (number) {
    FINAL.push(function clone(destination, source) {
      destination = destination || {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop]
                                                                                  ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop])
                                                                                  : destination[prop] = number
        ;
      }
      return destination;
    }({}, JSON.parse(_super)));
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(FINAL, null, 4);
```

So, i'm looping over the SUPER two times, one inside the other to test each object, and if i find equal strings, i increase the number by one and remove the object from the array, then i use this script to assign the number to the innermost property of the object:

```
  if (number) {
    FINAL.push(function clone(destination, source) {
      destination = destination || {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop]
                                                                                  ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop])
                                                                                  : destination[prop] = number
        ;
      }
      return destination;
    }({}, JSON.parse(_super)));
  }
```

But isn't working properly because of a conflict in this line:

```
    if (_super === current) {
      SUPER.splice(ii, 1);
      number++;
    }
```

I'm messing up the loop. Any ideas how to fix? I'm open to suggestions, i don't know if there is a better way to achieve this, i hope someone knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "Example Input" shows an array of strings, but your later example shows an array of objects. There will be a big difference in how you handle them....

Answer (score 0):

When you splice the array, elements are shifted to left by 1 but the loop index continues to move forward not accounting for this shift. You can account for it by decrementing the current loop index by 1 each time you splice.

e.g:
t = [1,2,3,4];

console.log(t[1]); // output: 2

//when you splice

t.splice(1,1);

// after splicing the array elements are shifted

console.log(t[1]); //output: 3

Working solution:

```js
let SUPER = [{
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "NAME1": {
      "12": {
        "10": 1
      }
    }
  }],
  FINAL = [];

for (let i = 0; i < SUPER.length; i++) {
  let _super = JSON.stringify(SUPER[i]),
    ii = i + 1,
    ll = SUPER.length,
    number = 1;

  for (ii; ii < ll; ii++) {
    let current = JSON.stringify(SUPER[ii]);
    if (_super === current) {
      SUPER.splice(ii, 1);
      ii--;
      number++;
    }
  }

  if (number) {
    FINAL.push(function clone(destination, source) {
      destination = destination || {};
      for (var prop in source) {
        typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null && source[prop] ? destination[prop] = clone({}, source[prop]) : destination[prop] = number;
      }
      return destination;
    }({}, JSON.parse(_super)));
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(FINAL, null, 4);
```

I have also initialized ii, number to 1 to reduce one iteration of inner loop.

Comment: Yesh, thanks for the answer, is exactly what i want.. but, do you know why the result is 2 when i insert a new object? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMxmge?editors=0010

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not working properly, so i need remove the "correctly answer"

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more careful before posting the answer. The issue was with **initializing correct start index for the inner loop**. Since you were using **for..of** outer loop in your example we could not dynamically calculate the inner loop index. I have updated the above code to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your own equals function and find the occurences for those in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one to set the "dynamically" changing rules then to perform this job is very easy by an invention of two Object methods; namely `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` and `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()`. Lets do it. Both methods take a number of arguments which are the object properties (if the argument is `"string"` type) or array indices(if the argument is `"number"` type). In addition to that, in the `Object.setNestedValues()` the very last argument is the value to be set. Just simple.

So here it goes like this;

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                              : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                                 this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                      : this[a[0]] = a[1];
};

var data = [
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}',
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}',
  '{"NAME1":{"12":{"10":1}}}'
],
   props = ["NAME1", "12", "10"], // this array is constructed dynamically !!
 reduced = [data.reduce((p,c) => {var v = p.getNestedValue(...props);
                                  p.setNestedValue(...props, !!v ? ++v : 1);
                                  return p;},{})];
console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced,null,2));
```