# Recursive to reconstruct object, and if already exist, get innermost property and increase the number by one

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
let SUPER = [{ "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }], FINAL = [];

SUPER.forEach(function(object) {

    var key = object => Object.keys(object)[0]; // pega key número um

    var self   = {};            // {}
    var oneKey = key(object);   // 'NAME'
    var keys   = [oneKey];      // [ 'NAME' ]
    var jointKey;               // undefined

    while (typeof object[oneKey] === 'object') {
      object = object[oneKey];  // { '1': 1 }
      oneKey = key(object);     // 1
      keys.push(oneKey);        // keys: [ 'NAME', '1' ]
    }

    jointKey = keys.join('|');  // jointKey NAME|1

    if (!this[jointKey]) {
      this[jointKey] = self;
      FINAL.push(self);
    }

    // console.log(self)


    keys.pop(); // keys: [ 'NAME' ]

    self = keys.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
      return previousValue[currentValue] = previousValue[currentValue] || {};
    }, this[jointKey] /* { NAME: {} } */ );


    self[oneKey] = (self[oneKey] || 0) + object[oneKey];

}, Object.create(null));


document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(FINAL, 0, 4);
```

Which is eliminating the objects with same properties and getting the innermost property of the remaining object and increasing by the number of past equal objects. Run and u will see.

I'm breaking my head to understand how this could work. Can someone give me a good explanation?

In the second for each iteration, the value of object isn't the second value in the array SUPER, how could this be possible??

Other mystery is this Object.create(null), which is changing the forEach scope, i'm searched about, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397211/confirm-number-of-occurrences-of-a-objects-in-array/

Comment: Not really, i'm trying to understand the code, since the person who made it didn't explain a lot.

Comment: @D_REIS: In that case you should comment on the answer, asking for a better explanation of the solution.

Comment: I already did 2 hours ago, i don't think the person will answer it.

Comment: some people take a break from SO to eat, sleep, have sex....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A re-written version for discussion below.

```
let SUPER =
[ { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } },
  { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } }, { "NAME1": { "12": { "10": 1 } } },
  { "NAME1": { "12": { "11": 1 } } }
];
let FINAL = [];

SUPER.forEach(function(object) {

    var firstKey = (obj) => Object.keys(obj)[0]; // first enumerable ownProperty key of an object

    var key;       // object property value
    var leafObj;   // the last object in a chain of first property object values
    var leafKey;   // the first key in leafObj
    var keys = []; // array of keys returned by firstKey;
    var keyList;   // "|" separated list of first keys

    // Create keys array while finding leafKey and leafObj

    for( var o = object;;)
    { key = firstKey(o);
      keys.push(key);
      if( typeof o[ key] != "object")
          break;
      o = o[ key];
    }
    leafObj = o;
    leafKey = key;
    keyList = keys.join('|');  // create keyList

    // initialize this[keylist] to empty array and push/copy to FINAL as required

    if (!this[keyList])
    {
      FINAL.push(
        this[keyList] = {}
      );
    }

    keys.pop(); // remove leafKey from keys array;

    // add empty arrays to a branch of keyList bush as required

    var child = this[keyList];
    keys.forEach( function( key)
    { child = child[key] || (child[ key] = {});
    });

    child[leafKey] = (child[leafKey] || 0) + leafObj[leafKey];

}, Object.create(null));

document.write( JSON.stringify(FINAL, 0, 4)); // for script in head section
```

Basically I approached the code as a maintenance programmer who didn't know what the code did or how it worked. Neither was self evident from a first read.

The structural rewrite of the first while loop and its preceding initializers was part of deciding what the variables were used for and giving them names. In particular I found the use of "self" misleading as choice of variable name. Typically a `self` variable is used to pass the value of `this` to nested functions in a constructor. Using it as the name of an empty array is not invalid, but conveyed no sense of purpose to this reader. Worse, `self` was reassigned later for unrelated use.

While `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.forEach` both call a function for each element in the array, I found using `reduce` to modify the structure of another array object while traversing the `keys` array confusing and swapped it out with `forEach` with a change of variable names.

The algorithm remains unchanged, I hope you can see how it works now. I would rate the original code as hard to maintain.

Comment: @Traktor523, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMYpMw?editors=0010 how could the this[keyList]; already find 2 occurrences in the first iteration?

Comment: @D_REIS there are two elements in SUPER in the code pen, so the first forEach function executes twice. Use `console.log(i, JSON.stringify(this[keyList]));` to better see how keyList is being modified. _I have also read on SO that Chrome treats objects logged on the console as "live" and updates the log as they change_.  I have not confirmed this myself.